# Block multiple programs through Windows 7 firewall quickly

Tags: windows-7, firewall, blocking, windows-firewall

I know how to block a single program through the firewall quite easily, but I have to do this for several applications now and the process becomes tedious. Is there any way to block multiple programs quickly in Windows 7 Firewall? Or just a way to block an entire folder.

A third party program maybe? (I'm refering to a GUI for the firewall feature in Windows, not an alternative firewall program).

Answer (score 2):

You ought to be able to write a quick batch file that applies your rules using [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”My Application” dir=in action=block program=”C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe”
```

I can't say I've tested this, though, since I'm not at my own computer right now (no admin rights).